# NHibernate proxy question

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a quick question.

If I have an interface from which my class derives, I can use that interface as a proxy for lazy loading. If I have an abstract class from which my class derives, can I use the abstract class as a proxy for lazy loading?

Thx alot!

Comment: Or I must derive my abstract class from an interface that will be the proxy for my derived class (from abstract)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you use an abstract class it has to be either a pure abstract class (i.e. no defined method bodies) or the defined methods have to be virtual.

Relevant doc pointers:

- http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#persistent-classes-poco-sealed
- http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class
- http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-proxies